# How to append to array in for loop?

Tags: sql, arrays, swift, xcode, sqlite.swift

How can I append my results in this array so I can use it later ?

```
 var animalQuestion = [(orderlist: Int, questionid:String, question: String, description: String)]()
```

This is my array which I declared in my class above.

```
let stmt = try db.prepare("SELECT * FROM allquestion_other where allquestion_other.name= 'animalChoice' and allquestion_other.id NOT IN (select answerresult.questionId FROM answerresult where answerresult.friendUserId='\(friendUserId)')")
        for row in stmt {

            let orderlist = row[4]
            let questionid = row[0]
            let question = row[6]
            let description = row[7]

        animalQuestion.append(orderlist: orderlist, questionid: questionid, question: question, description: description)


            }
```

When i'm running this code , i'm getting the error **"Cannot call value of non-function type '[(orderlist: Int, questionid: String, question: String, description: String)]'"**

row[4] row [0]row [6]row [7] is returning some values which I need to append in my array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
animalQuestion.append((orderlist: orderlist, questionid: questionid, question: question, description: description))
```

And do not forgot:

```
let orderlist = row[4] as Int
```

Your code incorrect because of:

1) For appending new objects to array you must to use array-method

`animalQuestion.append(<Array object>)`

2) In your case **Array object** is a tuple. So first you need to create a tuple, something like:

```
let orderTuple = (orderlist, questionid, question, description)
```

and after that appaned orderTuple to animalQuestion array like:

```
animalQuestion.append(orderTuple)
```

Comment: Instance method 'append' expects a single parameter of type '(orderlist: Int, questionid: String, question: String, description: String)'

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding?' to expected argument type 'Int' and Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int64' (0x111b28110) to 'Swift.Int' (0x111b28430).
Getting these as errors, still not working :/

Comment: let orderlist = row[4] as Int or Int(row[4])

Comment: Got it working! Thank for your help, here's the code : 

for row in stmt {
                
                let orderlist = row[4] as! Int64
                let questionid = row[0] as! String  
                let question = row[6] as! String
                let description = row[7] as! String
                
                animalQuestion.append((orderlist: Int(orderlist), questionid: questionid, question: question, description: description))
                
               
                }

Comment: The answer is correwct as far as it goes, but would be improved with an explanation of why it works and what a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) is..